# store multiple pysparks dataframes in a list?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

how can I store multiple dataframes in a list?

I have a function that reads multiple parquet files inside a folder. However, I need to create a list that contains the dataframes that are being read to do other processes. The expected result would be something like this:

dfs = [df1,df2,df3,df4,dfn]

Note: I'm working whit pyspark dataframe

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use :

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
files = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]
```